# Appending cell Value in Pandas for emptied cell in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cell

I have following table, based on the `St_date`, `En_date` is empty or not we have to merge the data in `Des` with upcoming rows till we find `notnull`

```
        St_date     En_date     Des         Ch      Deb     Cr      Tot
    0   01/06/18    01/06/18    CSH         NaN     NaN     1000    5786
    1   NaN         NaN         DEPOSIT     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2   01/06/18    01/06/18    DEP TFR     NaN     100     Nan     5686
    3   NaN         NaN         through     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

What I want is like below:

```
        St_date     En_date     Des             Ch      Deb     Cr      Tot
    0   01/06/18    01/06/18    CSH DEPOSIT     NaN     NaN     1000    5786    
    1   01/06/18    01/06/18    DEP TFR through NaN     100     Nan     5686
```

Anyone has Idea how to do using `pandas`?

Comment: So, the output has only two rows? Why does it still look like the "Des" column has 4 rows?

Comment: @coldspeed yes it would be 2 rows. I want to show the difference so it might look like there are 4 rows. But in `dataframe`, there would be only two rows

Comment: Can you show what you want the final result to be? Does it have it 2 or 4 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that (Note that I consider St_Date `Nan` like an empty string in the answer below):

```
# Add a field containing previous index if St_date is empty
df["idx"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.name if x.St_date!='' else None, axis=1).ffill()
df
```

Should return this :

```
    St_date     En_date     Des     Ch  Deb          Cr     Tot     idx
0   01/06/18    01/06/18    CSH     nan     nan     1000    5786    0.0
1                  nan    DEPOSIT   nan     nan     nan     nan     0.0
2   01/06/18    01/06/18  DEP TFR   nan     100     nan     5686    2.0
3                  nan    through   nan     nan     nan     nan     2.0
```

Then you can group with this new column and concat your `Des` field:

```
dfg = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('idx')["Des"].apply(lambda x: "{%s}" % ', '.join(x)))
# Then you merge the result with the original dataframe on index
df = pd.merge(df.drop('Des',axis=1), dfg , left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
# Filter rows with empty values in Des (not merged) and reset index
df = df[df.Des.isna()==False].reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

There you go :

```
        St_date     En_date     Ch      Deb     Cr      Tot     idx     Des
  0     01/06/18    01/06/18    nan     nan     1000    5786    0.0     {CSH, DEPOSIT}
  1     01/06/18    01/06/18    nan     100     nan     5686    2.0     {DEP TFR, through}
```